# Asynchronous Images downloading and display them in Gridview for android Xamarin interrupt the position in Getview

Tags: android, gridview, bitmap, xamarin, async-await

On the main Activity, I made a function which looping inside list of paths and download the images

```
      async void downloadAsync()
      {
        foreach (string item in string_List)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(Path))
                {
                    webClient = new WebClient();
                    var url = new Uri(item);
                    byte[] imageBytes = null;

                    imageBytes = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);

                    //Save the Image using writeAsync
                    FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
                    await fs.WriteAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

                    //Close file connection
                    fs.Close();
                }

          }     
       }
```

and on the grid view Adapter in the get view function put the code for loading the imageview

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
    {
       // retrieve the view
        View vw = view;
        ImageView picture;

        if (vw == null)
        {
         // code for create the image view
        }

        if (File.Exists(Path))
        {    
           Bitmap bitmap = null;
           bitmap =BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(path);
           picture.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
```

When I scroll on the grid to show the images, I find that the images on the incorrect places until the downloading is finished, everything after that adjust in the correct places.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your **BitmapFactory.DecodeFile** is running under the same task as the view, so it can make some errors on "downloading" the pictures

You need to run it under with the Async version of DecodeFile

Please try like this :

```
bitmap = await BitmapFactory.DecodeFileAsync(path);
picture.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, But I still have the same problem which is when I want to scroll on the Gridview it is called the getview (override function)  
which is interrput and get the false value for position parameter

Comment: So i think the best way, it to get all images in a List<Bitmap>. After that, loop in this list and add it one per one.

Comment: I see but as I told you the parameter position for get view function which is called from the GridView Adapter  return false value, i.e. when you scroll down instead of read the position as 16 for example return it as zero.